# MVC Core self-contained contains 4.6.x System.* dll's

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish

I have a VS2017 solution built on dotnet core 2.0 which contains an MVC Core web site and a netcore 2.0 console app and a number of class libraries.

All projects targets NetCoreApp 2.0.7

When I publish any of my projects as self-contained for linux-x64 I get an error when running on Debian 9 saying that System.ComponentModel 4.3.0 was referenced in manifest but that could not be found.

When looking into the .deps.json file I see that it references 4.3.0 but the file in publish output folder is 4.6.2x full framework version.

I tried clearing all nuget cache but still same problem.
I noticed other System.* assemblies was 4.6.2x as well.

I see no errors or warnings when building or publishing.
When looking in .nuget package folder for netcoreapp linux-x64 I find a System.ComponentModel without version.

I also tried publishing as win10-x64 self-contained and it still publishes 4.6.2x assemblies.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work on my own by using dotnet CLI instead of VS2017 to publish.

Afterwards I found out that my problems relate to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/857